# jQuery Ajax method succeeds, but no data received

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, post

I've spent over 10 hours on this problem and basically scoured the entire internet for a solution. It's a simply jQuery ajax POST method, one that I've used a few times before successfully. In the past I had this problem also but somehow solved it. The data I'm passing seems to be okay, in the network console of chrome it even shows a successful post with the supposed data. However, using .load to get that data always returns null. In the code below, I used a form that I prevented from default submitting to prevent a refresh. A button triggers sellBook(), which prompts a form, after which submission triggers post().

**JS**

```
    function sellBook(i) {
        $('#results').html('');
        title = books[i].title;
        author = books[i].author;
        ISBN = books[i].ISBN;
        publisher = books[i].publisher;
        image = books[i].image;
        year = books[i].year;
        $('#results').html('Listing for ' + books[i].title + ' by ' + books[i].author + '<br><br><form method="post" action="https://localhost/textbookexchange/db2.php" id="sellIt">Edition #: <input type="text" id="edition" name="edition"/><br><br>Price: $<input type="text" id="price" name="price"><br><br>Condition: <input type="text" id="condition" name="condition"><br><br><input type="submit" value="Submit"><br><br></form>');
        getInfo();

        $('#sellIt').submit(function () {
            post();
            return false;
        });
    }

    function post() {
        price = document.getElementsByName('price')[0].value;
        edition = document.getElementsByName('edition')[0].value;
        condition = document.getElementsByName('condition')[0].value;
        var formData = {
            A: title,
            B: author,
            C: ISBN,
            D: publisher,
            E: image,
            F: year,
            G: soldby,
            H: fblink,
            I: price,
            J: edition,
            K: condition
        };

        var url = 'db2.php/'
        jQuery.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: url,
            data: formData,
            success: function (data) {
                alert(data);
                $('#results').load("db2.php/");
            },
            error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                alert(xhr.status + " " + thrownError);

            },
        });
    }
```

I'm always returned success, never the error, as I get an alert with the data.

In my apache error logs I get this:

[Thu Aug 13 11:24:15.666854 2015] [:error] [pid 4255] [client 127.0.0.1:50476] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: A in /var/www/html/textbookexchange/db2.php on line 2, referer: https://localhost/textbookexchange/

```
   db2.php(the php file POSTED to)
   <?php
   echo $_POST['A'];
   ?>
```

I've tried parsing it as JSON, resetting contentType, setting dataType, setting crossdomain to true, async to false, using jsonp, using $.post, using less data (only one variable), and a handful of other things..

Heres a screenshot of network requests:
[image: The POST succeeds, showing data in preview and form data, while the get only ever returns null]

Comment: Look in the 'Headers' tab on the connection, and you should see what was actually sent to PHP. It's possible that javascript scope means that 'title' isn't actually defined inside post();

Comment: nice screen shot :)

Comment: Thanks, I needed to give some more context of the problem including a visual of my screen and keyboard.

Comment: I recommend to use Promise methods of the jqXHR object: `done()`, `fail()`, `always()`, `then()`. On [jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) "_Deprecation Notice: The jqXHR.success(), jqXHR.error(), and jqXHR.complete() callbacks are deprecated as of jQuery 1.8._"

Comment: @kchow FYI: You need to try that magic button out, it's really great :} (See the keyboard button: http://imgur.com/nsfc2T5 )

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`load()` creates a seperate get request, so there is no `POST` data for php to use. What you need to do is use the data returned from the post request:

```
success: function(data) {
    alert(data);
    $('#results').html(data); //.load("db2.php/");
},
```

Comment: I need my file db2.php to receive the data though. I want to insert it into a database, and return whether or not it was a success. This only outputs the data.

Comment: I also tried running load after the Ajax request seperately. No luck. Even after directing the page to db2.php there is still no data :(.

Comment: You already made a post request to `db2.php`, sending the data contained within the javacript `formdata` variable. the javascript `data` variable passed to the success function is the response from that php script

Comment: To clarify, directing your browser to `db2.php`, or using jquerys `load()` method, is making a completely seperate request to `db2.php`. php has no shared mempory - everything is created then destroyed **each request**

Comment: You can see this in your screenshot - you see first a POST request, then a seperate GET request.

Comment: I'm going to try and insert it into the database then. In the past I've always been able to redirect or even open a page seperately after posting and be able to see the data there. The error log still returns that it is undefined though..

Comment: Exactly, $('#results').load(url) is shorthand for "Load the results of a GET request to url into #results". What you actually want to do is to put the results of your ajax POST (held in data) into the innerHTML property of #results. So Steve's answer is spot on

Comment: The error log is referring to the second GET request, which of course contains no post data, so  `$_POST['A'];` creates an undefined index notice

Comment: `"In the past [...] even open a page separately after posting and be able to see the data there"` Thats just not possible, unless you are referring to a regular html form post (not ajax)